# how to remove console.warn message when i ran npm run test?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react when i **run npm run test** i get flood of below warnings please give your inputs

`console.warn node_modules/react-intl-universal/lib/index.js:101` 
`react-intl-universal locales data "null" not exists`

Comment: All the same warning? Multiple different warnings? Are there any more details provided in the console when the tests are run? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DrewReese Same warnings multiple times

``` console.warn node_modules/react-intl-universal/lib/index.js:101
react-intl-universal locales data "null" not exists```

Comment: Seems you're missing an intl context provider in your tests, or you just need to provide a defined locale (locales data) for when the tests run. What is your test setup like?

Comment: Here is my implementation through out application:
import intl from 'react-intl-universal';

 dispatch({
            notificationData: {
              message: intl.get('app.addCollection.successMessage'),
              status: NotificationStatus.SUCCESS,
            },
             type: NotificationActionTypes.SUCCESS,
          });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to initialize react-intl-universal somewhere in your test setup.

A good place to start is how react-intl-universal tests their own [code](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/blob/master/test/index.test.js).

Basically you'll need this executed before your tests run that depend on it (*sounds like a lot of them?*):

```
import intl from 'react-intl-universal';
// common locale data
require('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js');

// app locale data
const locales = {
  "en-US": require('./locales/en-US.js'),
};

intl.init({ locales, currentLocale: "en-US" });
```

If it's just a few places then I'd do it how they do, but if it's your entire codebase you're better off moving it into your test configs/setup.